# mounting VMDK images on opensolaris

Tags: opensolaris, vmware-vmdk

I know that VMware ships a vmware-mount utility with its server 2 packages on Linux that allow you to mount a VMDK outside a vm and treat it as a normal filesystem mounted on the given mountpoint. Is there a method for accomplishing something similar in OpenSolaris that does not require converting to a raw image and then back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution I was looking for  quite a while ago, however forgot to post it on here.

[vdfuse](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=33355) is a fuse module that will mount virtual disks as a block device. filesystems on these devices can then be mounted provided you have the correct driver available on your system.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox runs under OpenSolaris and can use VMDK images. Assuming your VMDK contains a normal Linux filesystem (ext2/ext3/ext4/xfs/reiserfs/etc) just create a new VM in VirtualBox with your VMDK attached and boot a Linux liveCD iso. From there you should be able to mount the filesystem.